# Expected value of a distribution function

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

> Supposed that you have two random variables: $X$ and $Y$. 
>   Is $\Pr(X<Y)$ the same as $E_Y(F_X(Y))?$

Comment: So what is $F$?

Answer (score 1):

For independent random variables, yes. In particular,
\begin{align}
\Pr\{X<Y\}  & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy \\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_Y(y)\int_{-\infty}^{y}f_{X|Y}(x)dx dy\\
& =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_Y(y)F_{X|Y}(y) dy\\
& = \mathbb{E}[F_{X|Y}(Y)].
\end{align}
Note that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $F_{X|Y}(x) = F_{X}(x)$.

Comment: Damn. I can't edit my question. It's supposed to be
E_Y(F_X(Y))
on the right hand side.

Comment: @J.333 Okay, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following assertion is correct (note the $\le$):
$$
P(X\le Y) = E_Y[ F_X(Y) ]
$$
because you can condition on $Y$:
$$P(X\le Y)= E_Y( P(X\le Y\mid Y )) = E_Y(F_X(Y)).
$$
Consider $Y=X=$ constant to see why the assertion is false with $<$ in place of $\le$.